# Node.js Deployd 404 error on dpd.get & 400 error on dpd.put when using id parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-400, deployd

Basically what the title says - I've been getting a 404 Not Found on all ids that I enter for "id":

```
dpd.items.get("id", function(results, error) {
 console.log(results);
});
```

And a 400 Bad Request on any value of "id":

```
dpd.items.put("id",{category:value},function(results, error){
 console.log("Record updated");
});
```

All the id values exist in the Deployd dashboard, and I am able to make get requests using any category parameters OTHER than ID.

Feels like I've tried everything at this point, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur if you insert documents through a different client than deployd.

From [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

> MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the default value for the _id field if the _id field is not specified ... if a client does not add an _id field, mongod will add an _id field that holds an ObjectId.

Although the IDs created by mongoDB are visible in the deployd dashboard, they are not normal strings (like the IDs generated by deployd) and deployd does not find them when it's looking for a string.

Try to run a query like the following with any other mongoDB client (e.g. [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/)):

```
db.yourcollection.find({_id: ObjectId("some_id_you_know_exists_in_collection")})
```

If it does not throw an error, the id is most likely an ObjectId that was not created by deployd.

Unfortunately, there is no easy fix. (At least not for big collections and complicated apps.) 
For SMALL collections I'd suggest to just duplicate the data into a new collection and let deployd create new IDs.

Quick, dirty and untested:

```
dpd.collection.get({}, function(res) {
    _.each(res, function(object){
        object.oldId = object.id //add id backup 
        delete object.id

        // post new object without id -> deployd creates a new id
        dpd.newcollection.post(object, function(res, err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            };
            if(res) {
                console.log(res);
            };
        })
    });
})
```

You have to decide for yourself if that works for you.

Comment: This was in fact the problem, I was importing in data from a csv. Was able to solve the problem by importing w/o ids.

Answer (score 0):

Deployd create crud API of any collection. 
Make sure collection name is correct try to use 
http://localhost:PORT/items/id .. if this will also give 404 then open
http://localhost:PORT/dashboard/items/events/ 
and On dashboard goto dashboard/items/events/ this will open ON GET panel, write there console.log(this.query)

and about 400 request , you write the code console.log(this.body) on
http://localhost:PORT/dashboard/items/events/#put-panel

This is the way to debug your API, deployd have some issue but better framework to create API instantly

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:5000/items/"id" also gives a 404. Console logs this:
Navigated to http://localhost:5000/dashboard/items/events
dpd.js:61 GET http://localhost:5000/__resources/items/validate.js 404 (Not Found)
dpd.js:61 GET http://localhost:5000/__resources/items/delete.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This logs the query { id: '301' } which should work because there is a record with id 301 but I still get a 404.

Comment: do you have data in collection?

Comment: if http://localhost:PORT/dashboard/items/events/  have 404 means you are using wrong collection name

Comment: Yes I have data in /items that shows in dashboard. dpd.items.get works when I use parameters other than "id", that's what's confusing.

Comment: are you using correct id value... like d6a432c10ee6db5c

Comment: Yes, the id value is correct and exists in the deployd dashboard

Comment: this deployd bug use the query dpd.items.get({id:value},function similarly for put .....https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/191

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to address this issue :(